# How I can put Widget above Widget using List<Widget> widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to stack multiple widget ?

I have widgets variable that wanted to be placed below `InkWell` widget.

How should I solve this ?

This is my code :

```dart
  final List<Widget> widgets = [Home1(), Home2(),Home3()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: new PageView.builder(
            controller: new PageController(
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
            ),
            itemCount: widget.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 5.0,
                  vertical: 22.0,
                  ),
                child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0,),
                  elevation: 1.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Hero(
                        tag: widget[i],
                        child: Material(
                          child: InkWell(
                          onTap:() => Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => Home(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child:  ..........?????????                         
                         ),
                        ),
                      ),    
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
         ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain what you are trying to do so we can better assist you.